# Changing DateField inserts on a trigger

Tags: trigger

I'm using a trigger to insert a list of invoices to a contract object, what I want to do is for the iterations of the loop have the Effective_date__c have todays date, then the second iteration be for next month and so on, is that possible?

```
if (sc.Payment_Type__c == 'monthly'){ //sc is the service contract
    List<invoice__C> invoiceMonthly = new list<invoice__C>();
    for(Integer intr = 0; intr < 12; intr++)
    {
        i.effective_date__c = date.today();
        i.vat__c = '13.5%';
        i.Service_Contract__c = sc.id;
        i.Invoice_date__c = date.today();
        i.Due_date__c = date.today();
        i.Net_Value__c = sc.TotalPrice/12;
        invoiceMonthly.add(i);  
    }//end for intr
    insert invoiceMonthly;
}//end if monthly
```

Comment: What is an iteration in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
Date d = Date.today().addMonths(intr);
i.effective_date__c = d;
...
```

This makes use of the Date class's [addMonths](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_addMonths) method.

If you want to move to the first day of the next month instead, please add that to the question.